# SQL Format and Convert functions in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format, sql-convert

I have a select and I need to format a few of it´s dates (in BBDD they are in YYYY-MM-DD and I need them in DD/MM/YYYY).

Looking around I found two different methods (both work OK)

1: `FORMAT(pb.FINICIO, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as finicio`

2: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), pb.FFIN, 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]`

This gives me some questions:

1. What are the main differences between using a |FORMAT`or a`CONVERT` in a select statement.
2. While it may be opinion based, which option is better? Again, I am doing a select.

The whole query:

```
SELECT pb.IDFACT, pa.IDGRUPO, pa.CNOM, pa.CDESC
    , pa.CESTAD, pa.CABS, pa.FINICIO as finiciog
    , pa.FFIN as ffing, pa.NMOV45, pc.TIP032
    , pc.NIF032, pc.NOC032, pc.FCO032
    , pc.XVIA032, pc.XNOVIA32, pc.NVIA1032
    , pc.CPO032, pc.EMA032, FORMAT(pb.FINICIO, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as finicio
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), pb.FFIN, 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY], 
pc.TEL032, pc.OBS032, pc.SIT032
    , CONCAT(pc.ap1032 ,' ' ,pc.ap2032 , ', ' , pc.no032) as nombreCompleto, pc.noc032 as nombreCorporativo 
FROM spt145 as pa 
LEFT JOIN SPT144 as pb ON pa.IDGRUPO = pb.IDGRUPO and pb.SVIGE = 'S' 
LEFT JOIN GACTB032 as pc ON pb.idFact = pc.FACT032
WHERE pa.SVIGE = 'S'
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for? Several product specific functions are used above.

Comment: SQL server as the core and a overdesign framework around it to make the calls with java

Comment: Then you can add the <sql-server> tag. (And remove <java>, since no Java is in the question or the accepted answer.)

Comment: you´re right, i will edit right away, thanks

Comment: What is BBDD?..

Comment: @DaleK In spanish is the way we commonly address relational databases

Comment: Ar, you need to stick to English on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaron Bertrand has an [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7144/sql-date-format-comparison-sql-format-sql-convert/) about the differences but generally, `FORMAT` is more powerful in terms of the control of the output but more expensive as an operator.

So, I use `CONVERT` if possible and `FORMAT` only for output which are not available with [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).